# Removing files in setup.py data_files using pip

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I am writing `setup.py` for my own Linux application. I added a desktop entry file, `myapp.desktop` into `/usr/share/applications`. Here is my `setup.py`:

```
setup(...,
      data_files=[
           ('/usr/share/applications', ['myapp.desktop']),
           ('/usr/share/pixmaps', ['myapp.png'])]
     )
```

I also included `myapp.desktop` and `myapp.png` in `MANIFEST.in`:

```
include myapp.png
include myapp.desktop
```

So I can install the app using `python setup.py install` and it also install `data_files` in the correct path.

The problem is, when I uninstall the app using `pip uninstall myapp`, pip dosen't remove files in `data_files`, to say, `/usr/share/applications/myapp.desktop` and `/usr/share/pixmaps/myapp.png`. I need to remove them myself.

How can I remove these files automatically using `pip uninstall`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  `python setup.py install` causes your package to be installed using setuptools, not pip, and as a result pip doesn't know enough about the package to be able to uninstall it fully.  Not even setuptools can uninstall your package, as there is no `python setup.py uninstall` command!  If you want pip to be able to uninstall your package correctly, you need to install with pip (`pip install .`), but that comes with the drawback that `data_files` files will be placed next to the installed package rather than at system root (e.g., `myapp.desktop` will end up someplace like `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usr/share/applications/myapp.desktop`).

Comment: I didn't know there is `pip install .`, that works well thank you. BTW I'm using Arch linux and `pip` seems to install the files at the correct system root path, but on Ubuntu 18.04 they are placed as you described. Very interesting.

Comment: `pip uninstall <pkgname>` gives you the helpful `Would not remove (might be manually added): <list of files>`  So pip recognizes that you might want to delete those.  Are you saying that it doesn't have an option to do so?